# sorting data on specific fields gives irrelevant data first in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, e-commerce

```
I want to search data in elastic search  version 5.2.1 such that the exact match term should come first and then all the relevant matches i.e fuzzy data.
The data needs to be sorted on the basis of relevancy (relevancy includes the creation date of item and then item inventory)

The query that i am trying is :

    GET dummy/_search
    {
      "track_scores": true,
      "from" : 0,
      "size" : 24,
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "bool" : {
                "should" : [
                  {
                    "match" : {
                      "itemNameWeb" : {
                        "query" : "swetashirt",
                        "operator" : "OR",
                        "analyzer" : "standard",
                        "prefix_length" : 0,
                        "max_expansions" : 50,
                        "minimum_should_match" : "66%",
                        "fuzzy_transpositions" : false,
                        "lenient" : false,
                        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
                        "boost" : 1.0
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match" : {
                      "itemNameWeb" : {
                        "query" : "swetashirt",
                        "operator" : "OR",
                        "analyzer" : "standard",
                        "fuzziness" : "1",
                        "prefix_length" : 0,
                        "max_expansions" : 50,
                        "minimum_should_match" : "66%",
                        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
                        "lenient" : false,
                        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
                        "boost" : 1.0
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "disable_coord" : false,
                "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          ],
          "disable_coord" : false,
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      "sort" : [
        {
          "createDate" : {
            "order" : "desc"
          }
        },
        {
          "itemTotalInventory" : {
            "order" : "desc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

The query above is not giving expected result as the exact matches due to sorting goes down because of sorting

The solution tried so far from the proposed solution adding constant score:

```
GET dummy/_search
{
  "track_scores": true,
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "constant_score": {
                  "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                      "should":{
                      "match": {
                        "itemNameWeb": {
                          "query": "fidato tshirt",
                          "operator": "OR",
                          "analyzer": "standard",
                          "prefix_length": 0,
                          "max_expansions": 50,
                          "minimum_should_match": "66%",
                          "fuzzy_transpositions": false,
                          "lenient": false,
                          "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  },
                  "boost": 2
                }
              },
              {
                "constant_score": {
                  "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                       "should":{
                      "match": {
                        "itemNameWeb": {
                          "query": "fidato tshirt",
                          "operator": "OR",
                          "analyzer": "standard",
                          "fuzziness": "1",
                          "prefix_length": 0,
                          "max_expansions": 50,
                          "minimum_should_match": "66%",
                          "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                          "lenient": false,
                          "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    }
                  },
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ],
            "disable_coord": false,
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "disable_coord": false,
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score",
    {
      "createDate.keyword": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "itemTotalInventory": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}

The sample output result from the above GET query 

{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 65,
    "max_score": 3,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "dummy",
        "_type": "search",
 
        "_score": 3,
        "_source": {
          "itemNameWeb": "Pack of 2 Men's Printed Full Sleeves Tshirt-M,
          "itemTotalInventory": 11,
          "createDate": "2022-01-10 15:22:47.0"
        },
        "sort": [
          3,
          "2022-01-10 15:22:47.0",
          11
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "dummy",
        "_type": "search",
        "_score": 3,
        "_source": {
        
          "itemNameWeb": "Pack of 3 Men's Half Sleeves Tshirt-M",
         "itemTotalInventory": 236,
         "createDate": "2022-01-10 15:22:34.0"
        },
        "sort": [
          3,
          "2022-01-10 15:22:34.0",
          236
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "dummy",
        "_type": "search",
        "_score": 3,
        "_source": {
      
          "itemNameWeb": "Greyson 5 Tshirts Size - XL with Track pants Size – XL",
          "itemTotalInventory": 60,

          "createDate": "2021-10-28 06:56:53.0"
        },
        "sort": [
          3,
          "2021-10-28 06:56:53.0",
          60
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "dummy",
        "_type": "search",
        "_score": 3,
        "_source": {
       
          "itemNameWeb": "Pack of 2 Shoes & Free 1 Slipper Size - 9 + 1 Wallet+ 2 Tshirts + 1 TrackPant Size - XL",
          "itemTotalInventory": 23,
          "createDate": "2021-10-20 06:22:08.0"
      },
      {
        "_index": "dummy",
        "_type": "search",
        "_score": 3,
        "_source": {
          "itemNameWeb": "Fidato Cordinated Polo Neck Solid Yellow T-Shirt",
          "itemTotalInventory": 4,
          "createDate": "2021-10-14 07:33:06.0"
        },
        "sort": [
          3,
          "2021-10-14 07:33:06.0",
          4
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "dummy",
        "_type": "search",
        "_score": 3,
        "_source": {
          "itemNameWeb": "Fidato Solid Round Neck Full Sleeve T-Shirt",
          "itemTotalInventory": 5,
          "createDate": "2021-10-14 07:17:32.0"
        },
        "sort": [
          3,
          "2021-10-14 07:17:32.0",
          5
        ]
      }
```

Fidato T-Shirt result should have come first but its giving Pack of 2 Men's Printed Full Sleeves Tshirt-M as top most result .

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap each match query by a `constant_score` query and give exact match's `boost` value higher than the fuzzy's boost value then if you sort by `_score` before your sorting criteria, you can achieve this. Following query should work for you:

```
{
  "track_scores": true,
  "from": 0,
  "size": 24,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "constant_score": {
                  "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                      "match": {
                        "itemNameWeb": {
                          "query": "swetashirt",
                          "operator": "OR",
                          "analyzer": "standard",
                          "prefix_length": 0,
                          "max_expansions": 50,
                          "minimum_should_match": "66%",
                          "fuzzy_transpositions": false,
                          "lenient": false,
                          "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "boost": 2
                }
              },
              {
                "constant_score": {
                  "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                      "match": {
                        "itemNameWeb": {
                          "query": "swetashirt",
                          "operator": "OR",
                          "analyzer": "standard",
                          "fuzziness": "1",
                          "prefix_length": 0,
                          "max_expansions": 50,
                          "minimum_should_match": "66%",
                          "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                          "lenient": false,
                          "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                          "boost": 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ],
            "disable_coord": false,
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "disable_coord": false,
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score",
    {
      "createDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "itemTotalInventory": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When i am searching with above query   "query": "fidato t-shirt" its giving top result as cotton printed full sleeves shirt although there is data with  Fidato Cordinated Polo Neck Solid Yellow T-Shirt.

Comment: Can you add some sample documents and expected results into the question?

Comment: Edited the question with the sample document and expected result